# What is the meaning of the name Zacharias Mulletstein?

Tags: etymology, names

I saw the name Zacharias Mulletstein in a newsgroup and thought "what a peculiar yet interesting name."  When I mentioned this name to a friend (because the post by this fella was amusing) they said "Oh come now.  That person really needs to get a better name."

So I'm wondering, what is the meaning of this name?  I couldn't find anything useful from Google aside from more postings by this person, and I neglected to ask my friend why they thought that about this name.

Thanks a lot for any insight you can provide, even if only for one half of the name.

Comment: A mullet is a type of hairstyle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullet_%28haircut%29

Comment: @JAM put that as an answer. The mullet is a derided hairstyle.

Comment: Are you sure it has any significant meaning? Maybe it's just someone's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Zacharias* is a variant of *Zechariah* which is a biblical name meaning "Yahweh has remembered".

No idea about *Mulletstein* (family names are almost always harder anyway), but I suspect what triggered your friend's response is that *mullet* has several meanings one of which is a haircut which is short on the top and sides and long at the back, fashionable in some subcultures in the 70s and 80s but later much-mocked to the point of being a punchline.

Comment: the -stein ending is almost definitely a reference to Frankenstein

Comment: Business in front, party in the back.

Comment: Wow!  That Zacharias variant explanation makes perfect sense actually because his messages are posted mostly in atheist forums, protesting atheism.  Since that poster is also a troll, the "much-mocked" part also fits well.  Thank you very much.

Comment: "Stein" is German for "stone". It is found in some Eastern European Jewish names, like "Bernstein" (burned-stone), "Goldstein" (gold-stone) and "Epstein" (I have no idea what an "ep" is). What this has to do with mullets I don't know, whether "mullet" has another meaning or if this is just a joke.